# How to get count 0 using group by if record not exist?

Tags: sql-server, join, query

I have sql server query and i want to get `count=0` if record not exist. I want to show all from `category` table , show all categories with `count 0` if not exist. But its return empty if record not exist in where `IN` clause.

```
  SELECT TC.DESCRIPTION,count(TE.CategoryID) AS COUNT 
  FROM tblEvent TE
  right JOIN tblCategory TC on TE.CategoryID=TC.NO
  WHERE TE.AssetID IN (
  SELECT ASSET_NO FROM tblAsset WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID=3)
  GROUP BY  TE.CategoryID,TC.DESCRIPTION
```

I want to show all `categories` from category table also with count 0. 
I am sorry, i cannot explain more, hope understand.I also try all the joins `left,right,left out,right outer` but its show empty but when record exist in `WHERE IN` caluse then its show data otherwise not showing `count 0` according to category table.

Comment: Word problems are hard, and reverse engineering "what I tried" is even harder. Please provide sample data and desired results. It *seems* like you should be using an outer join and *not* `WHERE IN ()` but that can only be a guess at this point.

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand thanks for response, i already tell you,, this query return nothing this is output of this query,, i want to show all the categories from `tblcategory` with count zero if record not exist in `tblevent` but it will show each with zero not show empty.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Yes I read the question, but without the additional data I asked for, it's still a big jumble of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hameed,

I believe the challenge you have is you used the `IN()` command as part of the `WHERE` when the filter applied to the "conditional table".

(If we re-write the query using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and some slight reformatting just to help me see it better.)

```
SELECT TC.DESCRIPTION, count(TE.CategoryID) AS COUNT 
FROM tblCategory TC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEvent TE
        on TE.CategoryID=TC.NO
WHERE TE.AssetID IN (
                    SELECT ASSET_NO 
                    FROM tblAsset 
                    WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID=3
                    )
GROUP BY  TE.CategoryID,TC.DESCRIPTION
```

What you are first asking the query engine to do is:

1. Get All `tblCategory` records
2. Find all related `tblEvent` records where `tblEvent.CategoryID = tblCategory.NO`

This ends up creating something that could look like this (I may have data types wrong for what is actually in your table but I just wanted to get a concept communicated):

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| tblCategory.Description | tblEvent.CategoryID | tblEvent.AssetID |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| Test                    | 1                   | 1                |
| Test 1                  | 1                   | 1                |
| Other                   | 2                   | 1                |
| Other 1                 | 3                   | 1                |
| A                       | 3                   | 2                |
| B                       | 3                   | 2                |
| C                       | 4                   | 2                |
| D                       | 4                   | 2                |
| E                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| F                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| G                       | 6                   | 3                |
| H                       | 6                   | 3                |
| I                       | 6                   | 4                |
| J                       | 6                   | 5                |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

When the `WHERE` condition is applied, this entire result set is then filtered to only show the records which have the appropriate `tblEvent.AssetID`.  For the sake of the example lets say that `SELECT ASSET_NO FROM tblAsset WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID=3` only returns the value of '1' and '2'.  What is then left over (before applying the `GROUP BY` and then `COUNT` pieces) is:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| tblCategory.Description | tblEvent.CategoryID | tblEvent.AssetID |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| Test                    | 1                   | 1                |
| Test 1                  | 1                   | 1                |
| Other                   | 2                   | 1                |
| Other 1                 | 3                   | 1                |
| A                       | 3                   | 2                |
| B                       | 3                   | 2                |
| C                       | 4                   | 2                |
| D                       | 4                   | 2                |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

If you slightly modify the query and put this `WHERE` condition as part of the `JOIN` your result set will be different but you won't loose the `tblCategory` records.  This happens because all the `tblCategory` records stay in tact (because we are `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'ing (which is the same thing as just `LEFT JOIN`, I just like using the `OUTER` word as well)) but, not only does `tblEvent.CategoryID` need to equal `tblEvent.NO`. But `tblEvent.AssetID` must also match the result of `SELECT ASSET_NO FROM tblAsset WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID=3` in order to come back to the main `SELECT`.

```
SELECT TC.DESCRIPTION, count(TE.CategoryID) AS COUNT 
FROM tblCategory TC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEvent TE
        on TE.CategoryID=TC.NO
        AND TE.AssetID IN (
                            SELECT ASSET_NO 
                            FROM tblAsset 
                            WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID=3
                            )
GROUP BY  TE.CategoryID,TC.DESCRIPTION
```

This should return the below table right before running your `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` pieces (again assuming `SELECT ASSET_NO FROM tblAsset WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID=3` only returns the value of '1' and '2'):

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| tblCategory.Description | tblEvent.CategoryID | tblEvent.AssetID |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| Test                    | 1                   | 1                |
| Test 1                  | 1                   | 1                |
| Other                   | 2                   | 1                |
| Other 1                 | 3                   | 1                |
| A                       | 3                   | 2                |
| B                       | 3                   | 2                |
| C                       | 4                   | 2                |
| D                       | 4                   | 2                |
| E                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| F                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| G                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| H                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| I                       | NULL                | NULL             |
| J                       | NULL                | NULL             |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

This result set should return the values you are looking for, or at least get you a lot closer.

Does this give you the guidance you are looking for?

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss alot bro !

Comment: @HameedKhan no problem.  I remember when this difference was something I learned.  This specific difference is something I use all the time.  I hope it helps you for the rest of your career!

Answer (score -2):

THE CODE THAT WILL GET THE DESIRED OUTPUT IS :

SELECT
TC.DESCRIPTION,
SUM(CASE WHEN TE.CategoryID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) COUNT
FROM tblCATEGORY TC  LEFT JOIN
(tblEVENT TE INNER JOIN tblAsset TA ON TE.AssetID = TA.ASSET_NO AND TA.EQUIPMENT_ID = 3) ON TC.NO = TE.CategoryID
GROUP BY TC.DESCRIPTION;

Comment: This would be better with some [formatting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help), an explanation of how it works, and how it differs from the existing answer.